# list.files with question mark

Tags: r

I'm trying to run the following command to get file names with only 2 letters in length, but it is selecting files with more than 2 letters in length:

```
list.files(path="/mydir/csv",pattern="??.xlsx")
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pattern=` argument takes a regular expression and "??" is not the proper syntax for a regular expression that would capture two letters. Try

```
list.files(path="/mydir/csv",pattern="^.{2}\\.xlsx$")
```

Comment: An important part of that pattern is the "^", which means "start of the string", without it the pattern would match the 2 letters before the ".", but they could be the last 2 letters in a very long name.  With the "^" it will only match 2 letter names.

Comment: See also `?glob2regex`, with `glob2rx("??.xlsx")` producing "^..\\.xlsx$"